# How to get data in grid view from procedure returning multiple rows in ref cursor

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, sys-refcursor

I have a package which contains a procedure and it returns SYS_REFCURSOR containing multiple records

```
    PROCEDURE GET_FILTER(VIEWNAME IN VARCHAR2,REPORTID IN INTEGER,FILTERNUMBER IN INTEGER, VIEW_NAME OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

      IS  
         FILTER_QUERY VARCHAR2(10000 CHAR):=NULL;
         DATAPOINTQUERY VARCHAR2(10000 CHAR):=NULL;
         INTERMEDIATEQUERY VARCHAR2(10000 CHAR):=NULL;
         REPORTFILTERS HCREP_FILTERS%ROWTYPE;
         REPORTTABLEFILTERS NUMBER:=NULL;
         TYPE FILTERARRAY IS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(100); 
         QUERY_UNION FILTERARRAY;
         FLAGFILTER INTEGER:=0;
         COUNTRECORDS INTEGER:=0;
         STUDY_DATE_CREATED DATE:=NULL;
      BEGIN
          QUERY_UNION := FILTERARRAY(NULL);
          FILTER_QUERY := 'SELECT * FROM ' || VIEWNAME;
          DATAPOINTQUERY := FILTER_QUERY || ' WHERE ';

           FOR REPORTFILTERS IN (SELECT FILTER_TEXT
                                  FROM HCREP_FILTERS
                                  WHERE FILTER_ID =
                                      (SELECT FILTER_ID
                                       FROM
                                         (SELECT FILTER_ID,
                                                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                                                                   ORDER BY ROWID) AS mRow
                                          FROM HCREP_REPORTS_TO_FILTERS
                                          WHERE REPORT_ID =REPORTID)
                                       WHERE mRow =FILTERNUMBER)) LOOP
            QUERY_UNION.EXTEND;
            QUERY_UNION(QUERY_UNION.LAST) := REPORTFILTERS.FILTER_TEXT;
            DATAPOINTQUERY := DATAPOINTQUERY || REPORTFILTERS.FILTER_TEXT;
            FLAGFILTER :=1;
          END LOOP;

          IF FLAGFILTER = 1 THEN 
            FILTER_QUERY := FILTER_QUERY || ' WHERE ';
            FOR indx IN 1 .. QUERY_UNION.count LOOP
              FILTER_QUERY := FILTER_QUERY || QUERY_UNION(indx);
              IF (indx  1 AND QUERY_UNION.count  indx) THEN 
                 FILTER_QUERY := FILTER_QUERY || ' AND ';
              END IF;
            END LOOP;
          END IF;

          OPEN VIEW_NAME FOR FILTER_QUERY;

      END GET_FILTER;
```

I wants to get/access records(possibly in array of objects) out of this ref cursor. How should I approach for it.
So far I have done code upto this :

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    DECLARE 
      QUERYFILTERS VARCHAR2(1000);
      MAIN_QUERY VARCHAR2(10000);
      v_cursor HC_PACKAGE.SYS_REFCURSOR;
      l_colCnt number;
      l_descTbl dbms_sql.desc_tab;
      v_name_var  VARCHAR2(10000);
      v_num_var   NUMBER;
      v_date_var  DATE;
      v_curid    NUMBER;
      v_row_num    NUMBER;
      p_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
    BEGIN
      HC_PACKAGE.GET_FILTER('HC_CA_VIVO',2,1,VIEW_NAME => v_cursor);
      v_curid := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(v_cursor);
      DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS( c => v_curid,col_cnt => l_colCnt,desc_t  => l_descTbl );
      FOR i in 1 .. l_colCnt LOOP       
        IF l_descTbl(i).col_type = 2 THEN
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(v_curid, i, v_num_var);
        ELSIF l_descTbl(i).col_type = 12 THEN
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(v_curid, i, v_date_var);
        ELSE
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(v_curid, i, v_name_var, 50);
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      -- Fetch rows with DBMS_SQL package:
    END;
```

This code only displays message saying '**PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.**'. What DBMS_SQL package functions should I use or any other approach and how please guide.

Comment: Honestly, It is a poor DB design and coding practice where table names and structure are not known before retrieving records. It could be insecure as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I wants to get/access records(possibly in array of objects) out of
>   this ref cursor.

Not clearly understood what you need but i guess you need to do something like:

Procedure with `SYS_REFCURSOR` as `OUT` parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sys_refcur_usage ( emp_output    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN   

   OPEN emp_output FOR 
   select employee_id from employee ;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      NULL;
END;
/
```

Calling:

```
DECLARE
   a          SYS_REFCURSOR;

   v_emp_id   employee.employee_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
   sys_refcur_usage (emp_output => a);

   LOOP
      FETCH a INTO v_emp_id;

      EXIT WHEN a%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_emp_id);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

EDIT:

> But Actually my table name is bind variable( in your example employee)
>   and the columns which these tables contain may vary. So How can I
>   declare column names when my table name is not known before.

Assuming you are passing your table name while calling the procedure. You can find the dynamic procedure below. But again you need to keep in mind that while execution you need to modify the `type` definition in `Anonymous Block` as per table name passed in the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sys_refcur_usage_dyn (
   tab_name         VARCHAR2,
   emp_output   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
   TYPE var IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (1000)
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   colnm      var;

   col_list   VARCHAR2 (4000);

   v_sql      VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
   SELECT cname
     BULK COLLECT INTO colnm
     FROM col
    WHERE tname = tab_name;

   FOR i IN 1 .. colnm.LAST
   LOOP
      col_list := col_list || colnm (i) || ',';
   END LOOP;

   col_list := RTRIM (col_list, ',');

   v_sql := 'select ' || col_list || '  from   ' || tab_name;

   OPEN emp_output FOR v_sql;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      NULL;
END;
/
```

Calling:

```
DECLARE
   a          SYS_REFCURSOR;
   v_emp      employee%ROWTYPE; <-- This you need to mention while calling
BEGIN
   sys_refcur_usage_dyn ('EMPLOYEE',emp_output => a);

   LOOP
      FETCH a INTO v_emp;

      EXIT WHEN a%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_emp.employee_id); <-- You can access columns as this way
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks. But Actually my table name is bind variable( in your example employee) and the columns which these tables contain may vary. So How can I declare column names when my table name is not known before.